# Saving a Set value and using it in get in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to do a simple operation of setting a text value and accessing it using get().

Scenario: I am working on a framework in Visual studio.

```
    private string saveValueName = "";
    public string GetText()
    {
        return saveValueName;
    }

    public void SetText(string output)
    {

        DynamicValuesManager.Instance.SaveValue(saveValueName, output, true);

    }
```

My problem: 
1. I need to save the value I am having in SetText and use it in the next step when I call GetText().

Would you suggest using a getter/setter in this scenario?

Comment: Why don't use a property???

Comment: Instead of using `DynamicValuesManager.Instance.SaveValue(...)`, why can't you just do a simple variable assignment: `saveValueName = output;`?

Comment: I am using the value in the tool where there is a specific dynamic invocation

Comment: Thanks all for the response. I was able to identify my mistake by your valuable answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a Property within C#.

```
public string saveValueName { get; set; }
```

Now you can use the property by call it, like this:

```
obj.saveValueName = "a sample name";
Console.WriteLine(obj.saveValueName); // Outputs "a sample name"
```

See this article for more information: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-overview

Answer (score 1):

```
private string saveValueName = string.empty; //better practice
public string GetText()
{
    return saveValueName;
}

public void SetText(string output)
{
   //save the incoming parameter to your private property:
   saveValueName = output //this really should be called input since you are passing it in as a parameter but no biggie

   //Not really sure what this function does?
    DynamicValuesManager.Instance.SaveValue(saveValueName, output, true);

}
//Sample code to retrieve the value passed in:
 tempVariable = yourClassName.GetText()
```

Comment: Why is setting the default value of a `string` to something other than the default value a better practice?

Comment: DynamicValuesManager.Instance.SaveValue(saveValueName, output, true); - > This does the function of saving the output to saveValueName during dynamic call)

Comment: @RufusL she is saving the string to "" instead of String.Empty. Besides the minor performance impact using string.Empty makes for code that is more readable: 
if(saveValueName == string.empty) 
reads better than other string comparison functions

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
private string saveValueName = "";
public string GetText()
{
    return this.saveValueName;
}

public void SetText(string output)
{

    this.saveValueName = output;

}
```

there is another way of handling this as well. it's called property in C#. you can do this:

```
public string SaveValueName {get; set; }
```

this way you can easily set the value for this without the need to call a function. for example for setting a value you would do this:

```
// obj is the object of the class
obj.SaveValueName = "some value here";
```

Comment: where is the output variable?

Comment: I change the `output` variable name to `saveValueName`, which then edited back to your original naming. the convenient way of naming arguments is that they represent the thing that they are being used for! you are setting the value for `saveValueName`, so it's better to use that name as argument name as well

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess (based on `DynamicValuesManager.Instance.SaveValue` call): you, probably, are looking for something like `Dictionary` and `indexer`:

```
  public class MyClass<T> {
    private Dictionary<string, T> m_Values = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    public T this[string name] {
      get {
        return m_Values[name];
      }
      set {
        if (m_Values.ContainsKey(name))
          m_Values[name] = value;
        else
          m_Values.Add(name, value);
      }
    }
  }

  ...

  var test = new MyClass<int>();

  test["abc"] = 1;
  test["x"] = 2;
  test["pqr"] = 55;

  Console.WriteLine(test["x"]);
```

Or even `ExpandoObject`:

```
  using System.Dynamic;

  ... 

  dynamic test = new ExpandoObject();

  test.abc = 1;
  test.x = 2;
  test.pqr = 55; 

  Console.WriteLine(test.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Moher's answer. you shouldnt write to a variable if its already set.

```
    private string saveValueName = "";
    public string GetText()
    {
        return this.saveValueName;
    }

    public void SetText(string output)
    {
        if (!string.Equals(output, saveValueName))
        {
            this.saveValueName = output;
        }
    }
```

also if your using MVVM style you will need to notify property changed when setting a variable.